# using __init__ method with and without parameters

Tags: python, class, object, initialization

I am new in python and please excuse me if my question is a basic question or is not clear.

I have a class in python and I want to set some attributes for my objects whenever I generate my objects from this class. I know, I must use `__init__` method for this purpose.

The problem is that I want to have this ability that I can set my attributes in two ways. For some of my objects, I want to pass some values to `__init__` method and set the attributes with those values. In addition, for some objects, I want to set some default values for attributes of my objects in `__init__` method.

My question: How can I have an `__init__` method that for some objects uses passed values for setting its attributes, and for some other objects, that are not passed, use default values?

Comment: Have a look at [default argument values](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values)

Comment: It is also a good idea to know the behavior of [mutable objects as default arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument).

Comment: thanks @elena for editing my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply equate the the parameters that you would want to be defaulted to their default value.

For instance, `__init__(a,b,c=0)` would give 0 as the default value to c which you can override by passing another value when object is created.

Answer (score 1):

```
def __init__(a,b,c='your default value')
```